# Creating objects in another class in java

Tags: java, object

I recently started working programming in Java for school and for a recent exercise i ran into some problems.

I currently have an object telephone, which can either be a mobile number, or a landline. 
Now i want to make another class, containing contact details. In those contact details, there should be two Telephone objects: one mobile number (gsm), and one landline number(telephone). The sort of telephone number is declared in the class.

My question is how I should change the initialisation of the ContactDetails class, to accept the two new Telephone objects. And what it is exactly that I am doing wrong there.

thanks in advance!

```
public class Telephone {
    private String sort;
    public String number;

    public Telephone(String sort, String number) {
        this.sort = sort;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getSort() {
        return sort;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public boolean isValidnumber(){
        if(number.startsWith("0")) {
            if (getSort() == "landline" && number.length() == 9) {
                return true;
            } else if (getSort() == "mobile" && number.length() == 10) {
                return true;
            } else return false;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}

public class ContactDetails {
    private String eMail;
    Telephone telephone = new Telephone("landline", Telephone.number);
    Telephone gsm = new Telephone("mobile", Telephone.number);

    public ContactDetails(String eMail, Telephone telephone, Telephone gsm){
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.gsm = gsm;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: And what is your question? Are there any compile time or runtime errors?

Comment: There's no point in initializing the **Telephone** objects outside the **ContactDetails()** constructor. Also, the way it is attempted is WRONG. And, this code doesn't even compile.

Comment: I will run to Doctor, and keep on saying "I have sick, please cure me", but won't tell Doctor what's the problem I have!!

Comment: Also this `getSort() == "landline"` won't work you need to compare strings using `equals()` method.

Comment: @Simze , thanks for your comment on the getSort() method. I am new to OO programming and java, still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. When initializing the `Telephone` gsm, you can't declare it as a `Telefoon`, as that class doesn't exist
2. You have to initialize the Telephones with a number String. `Telephone.number` is referring to the `number` String of a `Telephone` object, which doesn't exist yet since you're just initializing the `Telephone`.

In order to make both of these work, change the 2 initializations of `Telephone` in `ContactDetails` to something like this:

```
Telephone telephone = new Telephone("landline", "5555555555");
Telephone gsm = new Telephone("mobile", "5555555555");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for the second issue:this means that i should simply initialize it using a randomly chosen string?

Comment: @MeesVankaam you can initialize it with whatever phone number you want to store. I used a bunch of 5s to create mine just as a demonstration, but you could store any phone number in that string.